# How is the right way to use QProcess in Mac os X

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QProcess to get the Path of haproxy. Its not work well in Macos but works perfect in Linux.

This is a piece of my code:

```
QString haProxyPath = NULL;

// try to find haproxy correctly
QProcess shellProcess;
shellProcess.start("/bin/sh");
shellProcess.write("which haproxy");
shellProcess.closeWriteChannel();
shellProcess.waitForFinished(-1);
haProxyPath = shellProcess.readAllStandardOutput().trimmed();

// linux shows the right path
// Macosx just show ""
qDebug() << "HAProxy Path " << haProxyPath;


// ha proxy location not found if output from command is empty
if (haProxyPath.isEmpty()) {
    qDebug() << "HAProxy not found!";
    return false;
}
```

But If use `which haproxy` at Macosx terminal I can get the right value.

I used the QT documents as reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html

Some idea?

I Found one way to fix my problem but I think that is not the best way.
I'm checking if has the haproxy file:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_MAC)
    // verify if thw haproxy exist in Mac if not send an alert
    QFileInfo check_haproxy_exist_osx("/usr/local/bin/haproxy");
    if(check_haproxy_exist_osx.exists()){
        haProxyPath = "/usr/local/bin/haproxy";
    }
#endif
```

Comment: It’s because its location is not in your `PATH`. It will be if you launch your application from the terminal.

Comment: BTW, you are not programming in C language.  The C language does not have the `<<` overloaded as a stream insertion operator.  Please edit your language tags.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sorry I take off the tag

Comment: @molbdnilo when you say launch my app do you want to means: open the terminal by QProcess and than run my command `which haproxy`?

Comment: @LaionCamargo No, I mean that you should start a terminal and launch your application from there, not from your IDE or by double-clicking it. (The terminal starts a shell that sets up your `PATH` the way you expect.)

Comment: The issue is that on Linux, your desktop environment is launched from a login shell that sets up your `PATH`. OS X does not work that way.

Comment: @molbdnilo Ok, and you have any idea how can I do this work if need to open by double-clicking? Because I'm building for Linux, Win and Osx, so I want to get the output from `which haproxy` to know if have haproxy installed in OS X

Comment: @LaionCamargo Launching a login version of `$SHELL` instead of `/bin/sh` might work.

Comment: The more robust and flexible solution is to make it configurable from within your application.